# Implementing onActivityResult and startActivityForResult with LibGDX

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, libgdx

I am making an interactive map using LibGDX, and I need to start an activity on android from the interactive map. I followed the steps from [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup) and got `startActivity` working fine for a simple launching URL activity. Now I want to extend it to use `startActivityForResult`, but when I try to implement the `onActivityResult`method, it does not even reach into that method at all (no log output "hello"). How do I fix this, or other approaches to implementing the `startActivityForResult`?

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class AndroidWallUp extends Activity implements WallUp {
    Handler uiThread;
    Context appContext;

    public AndroidWallUp(Context appContext) {
        uiThread = new Handler();
        this.appContext = appContext;
    }

    public void openUri(String uri) {
        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUri);
        appContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void openWall() {
        Log.d("result", "intent start");

        Intent newActivity = new Intent(appContext, MainMenuActivity.class);
        ((Activity) appContext).startActivityForResult(newActivity, 1);

        Log.d("result", "intent back");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {Log.d("result", "hello");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);              
    }
}
```

Comment: are you comming back to your activity after firing an intent because start activity for result is called when you come back to your activity